# Error in rails3 in the controller file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is the code in the controller i am getting error pls help me

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @home = Home.all

    respond_with(@home)

    cookies['AFID'] = {
      :value => request.env['AFID'],
      :expires => 1.year.from_now
    }


    cookies['SID'] = {
      :value => request.env['SID'],
      :expires => 1.year.from_now
    }

    #cookies[:AFID] = { :value =>}

  end


  def create
    @homes = Home.create(params[:home])

    respond_with(@home, :location => users_url)
  end
end
```

I got following error 
NameError in HomeController#index

Comment: could you post more info on error? A screenshot or just text?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please use the Ruby convention of code indention!

And how about fixing `: value => request.env['AFID'],` to `:value => request.env['AFID'],`? Does this help?